# Serial upvoting reversed

Tags: support, reputation

What is the reason why I get -70 of Serial upvoting reversed on Stack Overflow, -70 of doing what?  I read the document

http://meta.Stackoverflow.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes

But I want to know which why in details why I get -70. Come on this is crazy

Anyone?

Comment: (From your profile) "*alright this is crap see ya stackoverflow ...*" - Ragequit!

Comment: yeah i think they created a bug NOT fixing one ...

Comment: Don't blame the system, it works just fine. Blame the person who randomly upvoted your answers several times a minute.

Comment: Well @Bart I don't know this person. ...

Comment: I'm not suggesting you make a house call. Only [Jeff made those](https://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/1165936105). ;)

Comment: This issue is unrelated to the change in the rep system. The anti serial upvoting system has been in place for a long time. The visualization of the change probably has improved a bit, but you would have lost the rep either way.

Comment: So, is [aki](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1051924/aki) your sockpuppet or your friend?

Comment: (From aki's profile) "*astalavista everybody, it was a pleasure to accept your answers, i had great time on stack overflow but this is the end of the road for me!*" - the sock is ragequitting too.  Good catch @Won't

Comment: the only problem here is that you are now being notified of the adjustment.

Comment: everybody: AKI WAS my friend, notice the **WAS** here, he is not here anymore with us

Comment: Seems aki has received quite some serial upvotes as well. Jan 17th for example....

Comment: so there's a law againts voting up your friends?

Comment: Yes, if you are mutually upvoting each other over and over again in a short span of time merely because you are friends, surely that's a problem. If you occasionally happen to stumble upon a question your friend has correctly answered and you upvote it for being a good answer, that's no problem.

Comment: @rcs20 If you go over their answers and upvote them, because you're their friend, then that's abuse. If you come across some of their answers and vote them up because they're good, then that's perfectly fine. I often vote up eric's answers on SO, because he consistently posts great answers, and the system hasn't complained yet. And it hasn't complained about me voting down Jeff(because he's the one who defends stupid policies) on meta quite often either.

Comment: wow I thought up voting friends was legal no matter the time frame, of course i up vote because they are good and i sometimes also vote down as well until they change their answer/question then i remove my vote down...

Comment: I was _really_ disappointed when I saw that I lost 100 points at once, but then I read the explanation and understood that it was perfectly valid.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It looks like this was serial upvoting to me. Here's the vote you have recently received:

[image]

That's 7 upvotes you received within 60 seconds. That's an average of 1 vote every 8.5741428 seconds. I am not a mod on SO so I can't see the details, but if all those votes were from a single user, then that's serial upvoting and those votes are not valid. The system was correcting that.

Comment: Looks like the 5 votes above that should have been included as well so the OP is lucky it is not 95.

Comment: ...nevermind the question upvotes above it. In fact, looking through previous days, there seems to be a lot of serial upvoting going on unless the times are inaccurate...

Comment: who gives a **** if I want to vote up, I can ... so if I open 5 pages (tabs) read them then vote for them at the same time that does not count? this is crap

Comment: This is not about you voting up various answers. This is about you receiving upvotes.

Comment: well then, it's worse .. how am I supose to control what/how people votes? I get punish because people UP vote me?

Comment: @rcs20 - You don't get punished. It just undoes the dubious votes.

Comment: No @rcs20, you didn't get punished at all. Someone else tried to abuse the system and the system said "no"

Comment: Looks like the system didn't work well. IMO the 5 upvotes on questions should have been reversed too. And your Feb 6, Feb 20 and Feb 21 votes look strange too.

Comment: well `-70 ` is good then? come on people who likes to get negative "adjustments" because the system say "no" ... am i missing something here?

Comment: @rcs20 The system invalidated some upvotes you received because it thinks they are fraudulent. It doesn't really matter if you just have a big fan, or if was real fraud. The votes are invalid in either case.

Comment: How is it being punished?  I'm glad Stack has these safeguards in place to make sure that someone can't serial up or downvote.  It improves the honesty and quality of the system.

Comment: I'm a mod and I can't see the details either.  Moderators don't have access to vote data.

Comment: @casper but you can see the suspicious vote patterns tool

Comment: @TheUnhandledException Yes, but note the statement was about "details", the suspicious vote patterns tool shows very high-level information.  We can't see information on the individual vote level.

Comment: @casperOne sorry if I led others to believe you could. **Voting details are anonymous**. I am a mod on Cog Sci and so I know what the suspicious vote patterns tool shows. Specifically when I said "I am not a mod on SO so I can't see the details" what I meant by "details" was "were all these votes from the same user. Which if they were it would have triggered a notification in the suspicious vote patterns tool... right? (Not sure because the only thing suspicious about the votes on CogSci is how few we have `:-p` )

Comment: I also became victim of this :(

Comment: @hitesh: you're not a *victim*, the votes were *fraudulent* and were corrected. Too many votes in either direction is not allowed.

Comment: @The  The Unhandled Exception : what do you mean either direction, does that mean even if someone tries to down vote all my question with 60 seconds it, points will be restored ?

Comment: Exactly @hitesh. The system is preventing users from voting on too many of a specific user's questions/answers,  either up or down. It's an abuse prevention mechanism designed to protect a malicious user from downvoting all your questions, and to prevent someone artificially boosting your rep by upvoting all your content. *Always vote for the post, not the author*

Answer (score 23):

Looking at your profile, the system didn't even reverse most of the serial upvoting you received. You probably should have lost >300 rep.

> **yesterday**
>   +5   12:25  upvote  php recursive folder readdir vs find performance
>   +5   12:24  upvote  mysql separating tables
>   +5   12:24  upvote  What are the differences between these query JOIN types and are there any caveats?
>   +5   12:24  upvote  CSS pseudo-code is not recognised by jQuery
>   +5   12:24  upvote  css does not work in chrome (linux and windows)
>   +10      12:23  upvote  mod_geoIP installation help?
>   +10      12:23  upvote  Move .htaccess content into vhost, for performance
>   +10      12:23  upvote  SEO for PHP URLs?
>   +10      12:23  upvote  Rewrite rule for Apache not finding URL?
>   +10      12:23  upvote  apache .htaccess rule with dynamic pages (php) performance
>   +10      12:23  upvote  append path directory to url using htaccess
>   +10      12:23  upvote  Detecting colors for an Image using PHP
>
> **Feb 21** 
>   +10      15:43  upvote  Move .htaccess content into vhost, for performance
>   +20      15:42  upvote  Detecting colors for an Image using PHP
>   +10      15:42  upvote  CSS pseudo-code is not recognised by jQuery
>   +10      15:41  upvote  Rewrite rule for Apache not finding URL?
>   +10      15:41  upvote  apache .htaccess rule with dynamic pages (php) performance
>   +10      15:41  upvote  append path directory to url using htaccess
>   +10      15:41  upvote  css does not work in chrome (linux and windows)
>   +10      15:40  upvote  What are the differences between these query JOIN types and are 
> there any caveats?
>   +10      15:39  upvote  mysql separating tables
>   +10      15:39  upvote  SEO for PHP URLs?
>
> **Feb 20**
>   +5   11:39  upvote  mysql separating tables
>   +5   11:39  upvote  What are the differences between these query JOIN types and are there any caveats?
>   +5   11:39  upvote  CSS pseudo-code is not recognised by jQuery
>   +5   11:38  upvote  php recursive folder readdir vs find performance
>   +10      11:38  upvote  mod_geoIP installation help?
>   +10      11:38  upvote  SEO for PHP URLs?
>   +10      11:38  upvote  Rewrite rule for Apache not finding URL?
>   +10      11:38  upvote  apache .htaccess rule with dynamic pages (php) performance
>
> **Feb 6**
>   +5   01:38  upvote  What are the differences between these query JOIN types and are there any caveats?
>   +5   01:38  upvote  php recursive folder readdir vs find performance
>   +10      01:38  upvote  Move .htaccess content into vhost, for performance
>   +10      01:38  upvote  Rewrite rule for Apache not finding URL?
>   +10      01:38  upvote  mod_geoIP installation help?
>   +10      01:37  upvote  SEO for PHP URLs?
>   +10      01:37  upvote  Detecting colors for an Image using PHP
>   +5   01:37  upvote  mysql separating tables

Some more votes for you look a bit strange too, but less blatant, so I'm not sure how many of those are abuse.

Comment: so the system has bugs then?

Comment: It's a heuristic, and a heuristic can't be perfect. In your case it probably erred on the side of being too generous.

Answer (score 17):

I just had this happen to me, too.  Yesterday, someone voted me 100+ points in about a minute.  Today, about half of that was axed.  I think users who respond negatively to points being taken away somehow are thinking that the points being taken away is a bad reflection on the user him or herself, which leads to negative feelings and a negative response.

Really, though, the points are being taken away because of the dubious actions of someone else.  At least some of the points should never have been there--another person put them there in a dubious way.  Focus not on the fact that points were taken away from you, but that the dubious actions of someone else were at least partially corrected.

This should not be taken personally, unless you were involved in collaborating with someone to rig getting a bunch of points for yourself.  Then you should take it personally:  your hard work of scamming the system just got undone.  Bummer.

But otherwise, you had nothing to do with this, someone else was screwing around and that was fixed.

Comment: +1 for an insightful reflection on the psychological impact of the notification.

Comment: It's as though you never received the upvotes to begin with - they are not real, so when they go - you aren't really losing anything you never technically gained to begin with.