# Is the serial voting correction script supposed to revert all votes or just a few ones?

Tags: support, voting, serial-voting

I [saw](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1810/franck-dernoncourt?tab=reputation) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210614031439/https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1810/franck-dernoncourt?tab=reputation)):

[image]

It seems there were 4 serial downvotes, and 3 got reversed.

Is the serial voting correction script supposed to revert all votes or just a few ones?

Comment: It's entirely possible that another user downvoted your post at coincidentally the same time as the serial votes.

Comment: Is it supposed/designed to? Yes. Is it 100% accurate? Probably not.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog true, just curious.

Comment: Per the FAQ on serial voting, [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me): *When the system detects this pattern, all of the votes cast from that user to the user affected are reversed*

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog yeah the FAQ is garbage in that department, it does this _allll_ the time. Especially if the votes occur over 2 minutes, 3 votes occurring (for example 2 at the end of 6:21 and a third at the beginning for 6:22) has reliably resulted in only the first 2 being rolled back

Comment: @Nick So then post a bug report, which links to the FAQ and quotes that section, citing example cases. This question simply asks for how it's designed, which is answered in the FAQ.

Comment: If you believe that you are being serially downvoted on an ongoing basis, and that the reversal script is missing a significant number of those downvotes, then you can flag one of those posts and ask the mods to investigate it manually. Make sure to include some evidence, like links to the unreversed posts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serial upvoting reversed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124251/282094), read the comments in the other answers too; **many** are **not** reversed; only most of the most certain ones, + secret sauce.

Comment: On MSE there has been lots of complaints about incomplete reversal. For example,  *[Serial downvoting imperfectly reversed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391406)*, *[Unsatisfied with partial serial downvote reversal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370699)*, and *[Serial downvote reversal bot possibly missed some downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297993)*

Comment: (MSO, not MSE (my own comment).)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/798831), under "How does the system detect voting fraud":

> When the system detects this pattern, all of the votes cast from that user to the user affected are reversed, and a "voting corrected" event is added to the affected user's reputation history to indicate what has occurred.

Assuming this is true, all the votes were reversed (another "supposed to be" next to the asterisk here).  The moderators also might be able to check it using their diamondy powers, so use a chat ping or a custom flag to ask them about it.